# mapreduce using NIO on HDFS

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs, nio

I'm need to put some text into an HDFS file from (all) the *Mappers* of a **map reduce** process.

The text / file is be used as a lookup in the *reducers* process so it cannot travel in the regular path (*context.write()*)

Using the below snippet is both slow and may produce file lock issues when activated from the different *mappers*.

I would love to use ByteBuffer and file locks (NIO). is this possible in this framework ?
Also, Any other ideas is welcome.

The code snippet:

```
Path fname = ...
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getconfiguration());    
out = fs.create(fname);
while (condition) out.write(...);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Thanks for any idea / help.

Raz

Comment: hadoop already uses nio..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would love to use ByteBuffer and file locks (NIO). is this possible in this framework ?

No, this is not possible to do on HDFS.

> Also, Any other ideas is welcome.

Take a look at how MapReduce creates its output.  There is a file for every mapper or reducer. You will have to write your intermediate file in this way.

```
part-r-00001
part-r-00002
part-r-..n..
```

> The text / file is be used as a lookup in the reducers process so it cannot travel in the regular path (context.write())

Keep in mind that this will probably be very inefficient in terms of network communication between nodes.  Especially if you are writing a large lookup file.

Comment: thanks @climbage .
I suspected this much , although FSDataInputStream does support ByteBuffer.

the only drawback with your suggestion (that I think I will adopt) is that any reducer will have to read all those file to create the lookup it needs....